# Is it possible to drive from Abu Dhabi to Riyadh? If yes, what is the procedure?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, borders, road-trips, saudi-arabia

I am planning for a road trip to Riyadh from Abu Dhabi. I have a UAE residence visa. I need to confirm whether it is possible. If possible, what is the procedure that I need to go through?

Comment: this will depend on your citizenship.

Comment: I am from India

Answer (score 2):

I have found an experience from a person in Tripadvisor.

Documents required for this can be found in their website as well: Original Passport with UAE residence visa page, One Photograph, copies of: Emirates ID, driving license, car registration, Tourism Certificate from RTA.

Here is the link for more read [click here](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g294012-i871-k10623763-Driving_from_UAE_to_Bahrain_via_Saudi_Arabia-United_Arab_Emirates.html)